# Responsive Site works like as on computer

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, themes

Recently I had decided to make my Wordpress website responsive. I took a non-responsive theme (Evolve) and made it like this http://gopuc.com . On the website when I shorten the window the website looks great. But, when I try to use it on my phone the site looks just as like on the computer. Let me know what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fort making your site to a Responsive Site Please eneter the Give Html And Css Code in Your Site.

**Html**

```
   <title>My cool site huzzah</title>

   <?php
     if (!$_GET['resp'] == 'no') { ?>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <?php } ?>

</head>

<body class="<?php if (!$_GET['resp'] == 'no') { echo "resp"; } ?>">
```

and **Css Code**

```
.page-wrap { width: 80%; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .resp .page-wrap { width: 100%; }
}
```

and check this Site For More Suggestion  Regarding  [Responsive theme](http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/)

Comment: Well, I'll keep waiting to know why you used this surname, because my knowledge is there're only 2 "Fidemraizer" in the world: my dad and myself... If you're not a Fidemraizer it'll be a good idea that you change your display name to another "invented" name and surname... Thanks.